# Is there any way to restore/recover my file that a rpm package overwrite?

Tags: restore, packages, rpm, file-recovery

I had some files on a server. Then I installed a rpm package that have same files in it. As a result, rpm package overwrite these files and I lost my newly edited files. I wonder if there is a way to recover/restore these files via rpm capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpm` does not create backups of files that are not marked as configuration files, so the changes are lost. However, `rpm` also won't overwrite files that exist in the rpmdb but have a different signature, and will refuse to install the package unless forced.